# Windsor transient lifestyle

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, castle-windsor

I have some very odd behaviour in my Windsor Container.

I have configured my container like this.

```
Container = new WindsorContainer();
Container.Kernel.ComponentModelCreated += KernelComponentModelCreated;
Container.Install(FromAssembly.This());

private static void KernelComponentModelCreated(ComponentModel model)
{
    if (model.LifestyleType == LifestyleType.Undefined)
        model.LifestyleType = LifestyleType.Transient;
}
```

So I was supposing all my components where I don't specify the lifestyle would get a transient lifestyle and it seemed to don't give any issues until now.

I start multiple asynchronous task which all resolve some components. (So you would expect every task gets a new instance of the component)

However now I know the tasks don't get new instances, because my tasks fail because of crossthreading issues with the component. (so it is being used in multiple tasks)

When I replace the Container.Resolve(somecomponent); With just creating the new component in place everything works like it should.

```
var contextProvider = MvcApplication.Container.Resolve<IDbContextProvider>();
```

replaced with

```
var contextProvider = new DbContextProvider();
```

So my question is what am I missing here.

The tasks are started in transient configured MVC3 controllers, because of explicitly configured.

The DbContextProvider is resolved in all repositories also configured transient, because of above code.

Another thing I found in the documentation is. You have to release transient components. I implemented all components with IDisposable. But because of auto contructor injection in my controllers I am not completely sure if I have to release them manually and if so how can I do this. (Yes I know I have to call the Release method on the container)

**UPDATE**

Code below is responsible for releasing and resolving my controllers:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        _kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
        }
        return (IController)_kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}
```

Is there some example available for testing if all dependencies are resolved and released the way they should be? (LifeStyle tests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what is causing your issues, but you should modify `ComponentModel` in an implementation of `IContributeComponentModelConstruction` only.

Check out the [documentation of the component model construction contributors](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=ComponentModel-construction-contributors&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) for help on how to effectively change the default lifestyle of the container.

Regarding disposal of `IDisposable`s - if you release your controller like you should everything will just work with Windsor :)

Comment: Ok, so releasing my resources like I do in my WindsorControllerFactory will also release all dependencies in my controller? See my update...

Comment: Yes - although, I'm wondering why you're using the kernel directly - why aren't you using your `WindsorContainer`?